# Gnome Shell Theme Not Changing?

Tags: gnome, themes

I recently tried to install the Hope gtk3 theme, to change the looks of the default Gnome 3. It's working properly, except for one thing: the top panel's theme is not changing. So, how exactly do you change it?

[image]

Comment: From what i can see..  you just changed the GTK theme, you *have* to change the Gnome SHell theme, get one and change it.

Comment: *Realm of the Mad God* is the best.

Answer (score 1):

**Manual step**

Step 1.

Backup default **theme** on `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` to **default-theme**

Step 2.

Paste your **new gnome shell theme** folder into `/usr/share/gnome-shell/`

(Normally theme creator will rename that folder as **gnome-shell**)

Rename new **gnome-shell** folder to **theme**.

Step 3.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> button.